What is this green powdery coating on a young cherry tree trunk?
It is Montmorency cherry on Mazzard rootstock.
The tree was planted about a month ago. I do not remember whether this green powdery coating was there or not when planting.
What is this coating?



Hard to be certain, but looks mostly like the remains of paint they used at the nursery to keep track of which variety was grafted to the rootstock before they planted it to grow out for a year or two and sell.
Second thought would be pollen from somewhere nearby.

Pollen is unlikely, as couple nearby trees planted at the same time do not have this.
